# music beat detection in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, fft, tempo

please anyone know is there any sample code for beat detection iPhone?.How to implement fft algorithm in iphone to detect music beats?.I see in one forum that apple's sample code auriotouch doing the beat detection, is it correct?.

thanks

Comment: Beat detection is _much_ harder than you might think.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really want to do beat detection, or you just want to show output level? 
AVAudioPlayer has

```
- (float)peakPowerForChannel:(NSUInteger)channelNumber;
```

method which allows you to easily create output level meter by calling it periodically.